# easy_install libmysqld-dev error :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'

Tags: python, easy-install

this is the error :

```
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/zjm_test/mysite$ ./bin/easy_install libmysqld-dev 
Searching for libmysqld-dev
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/libmysqld-dev/
Couldn't find index page for 'libmysqld-dev' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for libmysqld-dev
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in main

  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage

  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run

  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install

  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

what can i do,

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try to update setuptools:

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

Comment: Updating is worth it, because you get a much more simple error message. Before updating, I got the same error as reoirted by
@zjm1126 . After updating, I got "No local packages or download links found for xxx".

Comment: Thanks. I had to rename the easy_install.exe as easy_install.com, then run easy_install.com -U setuptools. Otherwise easy_install.exe is in use, and Windows won't let it be overwritten.

Comment: Indeed the above are correct,but 1 thing to comment on;When u issue 'easy_install' followed by the module you wish to install,the package should be in a format that python understands neither an archive or so.

Answer (score 4):

This error indicates that easy-install cannot locate the package, meaning that it is not found.
You'd be better off installing the dev package via your distribution's package manager (apt-get etc)

If you examine the output carefully, notice:

> ```
> Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
> No local packages or download links found for libmysqld-dev
> Best match: None
> ```