# Error wihle installing pwd module on windows

Tags: python, pwd

I am trying to install "pwd" module using easy_install on windows and running into below error,can anyone help how to fix this error?

```
C:\Dropbox\scripts>easy_install pwd
Searching for pwd
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pwd/
Couldn't find index page for 'pwd' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pwd
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install
    self.local_index
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
    return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016151/how-to-use-pythons-easy-install-on-windows-its-not-so-easy?rq=1 did the trick,I had to install setuptools again

Answer (score 8):

pwd is a built-in module(come with python installation) for **unix like only os** - you can't use it on windows, try winpwd

Comment: i get the same error when trying to install winpwd...how to install winpwd

Comment: sorry, I checked and there is no winpwd python package....what are you trying to do?

Comment: any package I try to install using easy_install I run into the same error ,how to install a package in windows,lets say MySQLdb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016151/how-to-use-pythons-easy-install-on-windows-its-not-so-easy

Comment: i followed it and have easy_install already,when I install any module I run into above erorr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178535/easy-install-libmysqld-dev-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-clone and tried to update setup tools but run into error `C:\>easy_install -U setuptools

Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/
Best match: setuptools 18.0.1
Processing setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg
setuptools 18.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing easy_install.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
error: C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe: Access is denied`

Comment: did you try this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601020/easy-install-exe-permission-denied-on-windows-8